# Programmatically Find Failed TaskAttempts for a running Hadoop Job

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

If I go into the task tracker and look at a running job I can easily see running/completed/failed/killed task attempts, and drill into more information about each them.

I'd like to be able to access this information programatically as well, but the [JobClient](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobClient.html) class doesn't seem to have any methods to access this information directly.  The [TaskReport](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/TaskReport.html) class returned by the JobClient.getMapTaskReports() and JobClient.getReduceTaskReports() functions seem the closest thing, but this only seems to have information about running or completed task attempts.  Is there a way to access information about all task attempts for a given task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a better way, but this is what I can think of:

Get the list of TaskAttemptID using following method of [RunningJob](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/RunningJob.html#getTaskCompletionEvents%28int%29):

```
 TaskCompletionEvent[] getTaskCompletionEvents(int startFrom)
```

And then, get each tasks status from following method of [TaskCompletionEvent](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/TaskCompletionEvent.html#getTaskStatus%28%29):

```
TaskCompletionEvent.Status getTaskStatus()
```

Comment: Confirmed that Task Completion events represent completed Task Attempts.  This was confusing because most of the documentation present implied that the represented completed tasks and not task attempts.